# Writing to a richtextbox with background worker

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, backgroundworker

I have been looking around for an answer to this but I haven't really found one

I need to write to a richtextbox while my code is running. Basically, I need to update the richtextbox with status lines like

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For i = 0 To 10000
        richtextbox1.appendtext(i.ToString & vbCrLf)
    Next
End Sub
```

However, I need to make the richtextbox scrollable while running, and as far as I have understood, I need to use Backgroundworker.

I know this is pretty basic for all of you, but if someone could help me out I'd appreciate it a lot.

Comment: There is no help to be had.  The whole point of a `BackgroundWorker` is to perform background work.  Anything to do with the UI is the opposite of background work.  You can only update the UI on the UI thread.

Comment: You haven't actually explained the specifics of what you're trying to do but one option might be to use a `Timer` to raise a `Tick` event repeatedly instead of using a loop.  For instance, if you set the `Interval` of a `Timer` to 100 then it will raise its `Tick` event about 10 times per second and you can update the UI on those 10 occasions. That will only take a small fraction of the second so the UI will be responsive for the rest of it.  Of course, that loop would perform far more than 10 iterations per second so it depends on your actual specific needs.

Comment: Are you familiar with delegates? I think you will have to create one to accomplish this. For quick 1-liners you can just Invoke() to execute something on the UI thread for a quick update, but if it's inside a fast loop like that, it will still effectively freeze the UI. But if you use a delegate, your backgroundworker can trigger some text updates and your UI will remain responsive.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Async Await, and within that use the Invoke delegate.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim cancelToken As New CancellationTokenSource

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Await Task.Run(Sub()
                       For i = 0 To 10000
                           Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
                           RichTextBox1.Invoke(Sub()
                                                   RichTextBox1.AppendText(i.ToString & vbCrLf)
                                               End Sub)
                           If cancelToken.IsCancellationRequested Then
                               Return
                           End If
                       Next
                   End Sub)
End Sub

Private Sub bnCancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles bnCancel.Click
    cancelToken.Cancel()
End Sub
End Class
```

I've added the Sleep in there to imitate a time consuming method. I've also included a CancellationTokenSource to demonstrate how to stop.

This can only be used for .NET Framework 4.5 and higher